# Select item from JCombobox and delete the row in database

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, jcombobox, sql-delete

I am working on a project in which I have a SQLite database with a table called Table1 and values title/location without an ID as column etc...

My form has a combobox which I've managed to get it display my DB each entry in one row . Now I want with a button "Delete" to delete the row that I have selected in the combobox and I am kind of lost.

Here is my code for the combobox (I think it's fine):

```
private void FillCombo(){
    try {
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");        
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\users\\Kajou\\momentsdb.sqlite");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Table1");

        while (resultSet.next()) {    
            comboBox1.addItem(resultSet.getString("Title") + " " + "Date:" + resultSet.getString("Day")+"/"+ resultSet.getString("Month") +"/" + resultSet.getString("Year") + " " + resultSet.getString("Location")+ " " + resultSet.getString("Mood"));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And now about the button delete. I've tried few things but looks like not going well:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");                
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\users\\Kajou\\momentsdb.sqlite");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        String sql = "DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE col_string=Title";
        int deleteCount = statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        sql = "DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE col_string=?";
        pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,"a string");
        deleteCount=pst.executeUpdate();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DeleteImportantMomentsForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DeleteImportantMomentsForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your question, welcome to StackOverflow. Well, you probably got some exception or stacktrace on your console. They would be clarifying the situation, or at least a more precise question than "this kinda not works" would be nice. It is hard to say what is missing without any more info.

Comment: it cant trace the string i am giving thats the error i get . i dont know how to delete the selected item from combobox thats the main problem and i was hoping to some help or an example like that . i cant find anything similar at google or with the search here

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
Object item = comboBox.getSeletedItem();
pst.setString(1, item.toString());
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but since i am new to all that can u tell me where to put those commands?or if you can edit it i d be thankfull

Comment: @user3046729, seriously? I added one line of code and changed another. Where do you think the code goes?

Answer (score 0):

First off, sorry for the extension but I have several advices for you :)

> 1) My form has a combobox which i managed to get it display my DB each
>   entry in one row

Here is the way you're adding an entry to the combo box:

```
comboBox1.addItem(resultSet.getString("Title") + " " + "Date:" + 
                   resultSet.getString("Day")+"/"+ 
                   resultSet.getString("Month") +"/" + 
                   resultSet.getString("Year") + " " + 
                   resultSet.getString("Location")+ " " + 
                   resultSet.getString("Mood"));
```

This way you'll get a very large string added to your combo box, which is not *bad* but can be highly improved if you map this info into a domain class. For instance:

```
class MyClass {
    int day, month, year;
    String title, location, mood;

    public MyClass(int day, int month, int year, 
                   String title, String location, String mood) {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year,
        this.title = title;
        this.location = location;
        this.mood = mood;
    }

    // getters and setters are up to you :)
}
```

Next step is adding new `MyClass` objects to your combo box:

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(resultSet.getInt("Day"),
                                  resultSet.getInt("Month"),
                                  resultSet.getInt("Year"),
                                  resultSet.getString("Title"),
                                  resultSet.getString("Location"),
                                  resultSet.getString("Mood"));
    comboBox1.addItem(myClass); // see note below
}
```

**Note:** Swing components (such as `JComboBox`) must be created and updated in the [Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (a.k.a. EDT) which is a single and special thread. If you have a heavy task running in the EDT (for instance database connections) then this task may block the EDT and your GUI will freeze and Swing components won't be able to work (or even display) untill this task is done. To avoid this issue there are some tools you can use to make the heavy tasks in a separate thread and update Swing components in the EDT, for instance [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). For further information take a look to [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

So I would suggest you make database calls using a `SwingWorker`:

```
SwingWorker<Void,MyClass> worker = new SwingWorker<Void,MyClass>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception { // this take place in a background thread
        // connect to the database and execute the query here
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass(resultSet.getInt("Day"), ...);
            publish(myClass);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<MyClass> chunks){ // this take place in the EDT
        for(MyClass myClass : chunks){
            comboBox1.addItem(myClass);
        }
    }
}
```

Well now you have the items properly added to your combo box. Next step is make the combo box display the text as you wish. To do so you'll need to implement a [ListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html). Take a look to [Providing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) section in [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) tutorial. Take a look to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732777/is-jlist-override-the-list-automatic-bug/19733848#19733848). It's about setting a custom renderer to a `JList` but exactly the same applies to `JComboBox`.

> 2) Now i want with a button "delete" to delete the row that i have
>   selected in the combobox and i am kind of lost

Please note you're trying to execute two different delete queries:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE col_string=Title"; // This doesn't make sense
int deleteCount = statement.executeUpdate(sql); 
sql = "DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE col_string=?"; // This looks better I guess
pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
```

I suspect one of these queries (if not both of them) throws an Exception.

As your combo box will contain `MyClass` objects, you can make this change at the action performed method:

```
MyClass myClass = (MyClass)comboBox1.getSelectedItem();
String sql = "DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Title = ?"; //If Title is the name of the column, of course
PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1,myClass.getTitle());
```

**Note:** Once again, the action performed method is executed in the EDT. You should move the database call to a background thread to avoid blocking the EDT.

Comment: Wow thank you very much for your answer and your help ! on the last [code] Title is only one of my column i have 5 more in the same row so if i want to delete the whole row i just add the other columns too?
Thanks again time for work :)

Comment: @user3046729 you're welcome! :) *Title is only one of my column i have 5 more in the same row so if i want to delete the whole row i just add the other columns too?* Not necessarily. A [DELETE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) statement will delete the whole row(s) that matches with all conditions defined in WHERE clause. In the example if you have two records (tuples) with exactly the same title, then both will be deleted. So be careful and make sure your WHERE clause is defined properly ;)