# Mistakes with table clicked fetching from DB

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

can you help me. I got stock in my project..
when I retrieve Resultset, it doesn't appear in field when I click on the table..
the code is below..

```
private void table_lectureKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                         
  if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP ){

    try {
      int row=table_lecture.getSelectedRow();
      String Table_Clicked=table_lecture.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
      String sql="Select * from Lectures where Lecture_ID='"+Table_Clicked+"' ";
      ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
      rs=ps.executeQuery();    

      if (rs.next()) {
       try {
         String add1=rs.getString("Lecture_ID").toString();
         txt_LectureNO.setText(add1);
         String add2=rs.getString("Lecture_Name");
         txt_lecture.setText(add2);
         String add3=rs.getString("Lecture_Date");
         dtc_Date.setDateFormatString(add3);
         String add4=rs.getString("Lecture_Time");
         txt_Time.setText(add4);
         String add5=rs.getString("Lecturer");
         txt_Lecturer.setText(add5);
         String add6=rs.getString("Lecture_Place");
         txt_Place.setText(add6);
         String add7=rs.getString("Audiance");
         txt_Audiance.setText(add7);
         String add8=rs.getString("Remark");
         txp_Remarks.setText(add8);
       } catch(Exception e) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
      }
    } catch(Exception e ){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }          
  }   
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: your question is unclear to me, did you get any error message? is yes then post it.

Comment: yes I got { Microsoft [ODBC Microsoft Access Drver] Data type Mismatch criteria Expression

Comment: 1) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..` 2) For better help sooner, post a [Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCTRE).

Comment: my entire project seem has same problem. can anyone see it http://www.gulfup.com/?GVqln1

Comment: Tip:  Add @Jugadu (or whoever - the `@` is important) to *notify* them of a new comment.

Comment: *"can anyone see it"*  Many people cannot or will not follow external links.  Post an MCTRE as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21524191/edit).

Answer (score 4):

Note your SQL statement:

```
"Select * from Lectures where Lecture_ID='"+Table_Clicked+"' "
```

This statement will be parsed in something like this:

```
Select * from Lectures where Lecture_ID = '1'
```

Tipically an ID is a numerical data type, so I suspect the problem is in your SQL statement giving you an empty result set (or causing an `SQLException`). In addition your query is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

To avoid these issues you need to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) properly:

```
int row = table_lecture.getSelectedRow();
Object tableClicked = table_lecture.getValueAt(row, 0);
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Lectures WHERE Lecture_ID = ?";
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setObject(1, tableClicked);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

---

Some hints on your code:

```
int row = table_lecture.getSelectedRow();
String Table_Clicked = table_lecture.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
```

Here `row` is the selected row number in the ***view*** not the ***model***, so you should request the proper value. You have two options:

#### Request value to the table

```
int row = table_lecture.getSelectedRow();
String Table_Clicked = table_lecture.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
```

#### Convert view index in its respective model index

```
int row = table_lecture.getSelectedRow();
int modelIndex = table_lecture.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
String Table_Clicked = table_lecture.getModel().getValueAt(modelIndex , 0).toString();
```

---

It's preferable use [Keybinding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over [KeyListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) when you're working with Swing for the reasons discussed in this topic: [Key bindings vs. key listeners in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290035/key-bindings-vs-key-listeners-in-java/15290065#15290065).

In this particular case I wouldn't use keybinding either but use [ListSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) instead:

```
table_lecture.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
     @Override
     public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
         // your code here
     }
 });
```

---

Database calls are time consuming tasks and may block the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (a.k.a. EDT) causing the GUI become unresponsive. The EDT is a single and special thread where Swing components creation and update take place. To avoid block this thread consider use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to perform database calls in a background thread and update Swing components in the EDT. See more in [Concurrency in Swing trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

I'd suggest you take a look to the hints exposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361363/java-select-from-combobox-and-delete-the-row/20363649#20363649). Summarized:

- Wrap data in a domain class.
- Use a SwingWorker to do the database calls in a background thread and
  update Swing components in the EDT.

---

Finally but not less important, alway follow [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)

Comment: I'm not sure if you've struck the answer here (mostly because of uncertainty about the question) but +1 for the slew of excellent advice.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank you. Honestly at first time it was more like a guess but based on this OP's comment: *"yes I got { Microsoft [ODBC Microsoft Access Drver] Data type Mismatch criteria Expression"* I think the problem is clearly in SQL statement.